# Browser not sending back the HTTPonly cookie back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am working on a project using the MERN stack.

When a request is send to the login end point, the client return access token as JSON and refresh token as res.cookies. Here is the sample code

```js
const login = asyncHandler(async (req, res) =>{
const accessToken = 1234
const refreshToken = 5678
res.cookie("jwt", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true, 
    secure: false, 
    sameSite: "None",
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
    path: "/auth/refresh",
  });
  res.json({ accessToken });
}
```

When a request is send to the refresh end point, as per my logic the httponly cookie should be send automatically to client and the client should return access token as json. Here is sample code

```js
const refresh = (req, res) => {
  console.log("inside refresh");
  const cookies = req.cookies;
  console.log("cookies", cookies);

  if (!cookies?.jwt) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "Unauthorized:No refresh token cookie found" });
  }

  const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    asyncHandler(async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .json({ message: "Forbidden: Wrong refresh token cookie" });
      }

      const foundUser = await User.findOne({ username: decoded.username });
      if (!foundUser) {
        res
          .status(401)
          .json({ message: "Unauthorized: wrong cookie send, no user found" });
      }

      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
          UserInfo: {
            username: foundUser.username,
            roles: foundUser.roles,
          },
        },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "20" }
      );
      res.json({ accessToken });
    })
  );
};
```

## **Server Side Refresh Function

````js
export async function refresh() {
  const res = await axios.get("/auth/refresh", {
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  return res.accessToken;
}```



Now when I am doing the following steps

1)Sending login request to the client; I confirmed that the access token is returned and the HTTPonly cookie is stored as set-cookie in the res headers
2)Sending refresh request to the client using refresh function in the client side; The refresh end point is not getting the acces to the HTTPcookie?. When trying to print the cookie in the refresh end point, the cookie is returned as [Object: null prototype]

What am I doing wrong?
````

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) - *if SameSite=None then the Secure attribute must also be set* - perhaps that's what you did wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX , Tried using different combinations. But still the browser is not sending the cookie back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Adding {withCredentials:true} to the login request solved the problem